# WPF C# buttons isEnabled false gray out whole button

Tags: c#, wpf, button

i have 2 issues here  First , i have a few buttons , but when i try to disable them by doing

> button6.IsEnabled = false;

Yes , my button is disabled but the image for my button is gone too , i want it to be like asp.net , where buttons disabled only disallow them to click but the image of the buton is still there.

2nd , i have some user control page which consist of a button but whenever i try to switch to that user control page within the MainWindow , the buttons on the user control page turn to be disabled and turns white .

In mainwindow on how i switch the pages within the window:

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Story
    {



        Story page = new Story();
        pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        GridHome.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        pageTransition1.ShowPage(page);

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // Sing-Along
    {
        SingAlong page = new SingAlong();
        pageTransition1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        GridHome.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        pageTransition1.ShowPage(page);


    }
```

Story and SingAlong is my user control page name .

Comment: For the first query try to IsHitTestVisible="False" instead of IsEnabled="False" for Button.

Comment: You're going to have to elaborate on the first issue of the button disappearing on `.IsEnabled = false;`. In my WPF app the buttons behave as you'd like.

Comment: Button images do not disappear on disabling so you have some code\XAML that explicitly does that. But it\`s hard to tell since you did not post any XAML. Second issue may be related to commands CanExecute or moon cycles - hard tell without any code either.

Comment: Have you got custom button templates? It may be that the template is changing the visible content therefore hiding the image. Can you post a working example with xaml?

Comment: Show the XAML please, as the error is not in the code you provided.

Comment: Ravuthasamy's comment should be accepted as the answer.